# Matching initialized integer values

Tags: php, regex, perl

Let's say for an instance I have this string:

`var a=23434,bc=3434,erd=5656,ddfeto='dsf3df34dff3',eof='sdfwerwer34',wer=4554;`

How should I match all the initializations assigned as integer? Here's my current try, but I don't understand why it's matching everything.

```
$pattern = '/var (.*=\d)/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$page,$matches);
```

EDIT: I'm trying to match each initialization:

```
1 => a=23434
2 => bc=3434
```

and so on...

EDIT: Here's an update on my try:

```
$pattern = '/[^v^a^r] (.*=\d+),/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$page,$matches);

0 => 'var a=23434,bc=3434,erd=5656,'
1 => 'a=23434,bc=3434,erd=5656'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is using "greedy" matching.  You don't want that.  In PHP, you can either follow your wildcard with a `?` to specify non-greedy matching, as in:

```
$pattern = '/var (.*?=\d)/';
```

or using the `U` flag [as documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), as in:

```
$pattern = '/var (.*=\d)/U';
```

which will make all wildcards use non-greedy matching.

EDIT: Also, since you're including "var", you would probably need to change it to

```
$pattern = '/var (.*?=\d)*/';
```

or

```
$pattern = '/var (.*=\d)*/U';
```

to match any number of `(.*=\d)` patterns.

---

***EDIT:*** Update per discussion:

**PHP**

```
$page = "var a=23434,bc=3434,erd=5656,ddfeto='dsf3df34dff3',eof='sdfwerwer34',wer=4554;";
$pattern = '/([a-zA-Z]+=\d+)/';

preg_match_all($pattern,$page,$matches);


print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Produces**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a=23434
    [1] => bc=3434
    [2] => erd=5656
    [3] => wer=4554
)
```

Note: This filters *out* the entries that have the RHS enclosed in single quotes.  If you don't want that, let us know.

---

***EDIT #2***: My answer to your question exceeded the size of the comment box so I edited my answer.

The `[a-zA-z]` expression matches only alphabetical characters of either case.  Note that the updated code also removed the "ungreedy" modifier, so we actually *want* it to be greedy now.  And since we want it to be greedy, the `.` will "eat" too much.  Go ahead, play around with the code, see what happens  when you change it to `.*` it is a good opportunity to get more familiar with regex.

Since the `.` "eats" too much, we need to restrict it from matching all characters to matching the ones we want.  We could have used something like

```
$pattern = '/([^\s,]*=\d+)/';
```

where the `[^\s,]*` would match any number of non-whitespace, non-comma characters.  This  would also have worked for your test cases.

But in this case, we can say confidently what the characters we want to include are, so instead of "blacklisting" characters, we'll "whitelist" them.  In this case we specify that we want to match any alphabetical character of either case.

As is the case with many things, especially in programming, there are many ways to skin a cat.  There are a number of alternative regex patterns that would have also worked for your test cases.  Its up to you to understand the limits of each, how they will perform on edge cases, and how maintainable they are, and make a decision.

Comment: it only matched the first initialization

Comment: Hi, could you explain why you used `[a-zA-Z]` instead of just `.`? Thanks.

Comment: @Barsoom, since my answer was too long, I edited my post in response -- see Edit #2.

Comment: Thanks so much @jedwards I appreciate your explanation, a great way to really learn how stuff works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use regex:

```
$string = substr($string, 4); // remove the first 4 characters, 'var '
$pairs = explode(',', $string); // split using the comma
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);
    if (is_int($value)) {
        // this is an integer
    } else {
        // not an integer
    }
}
```

Comment: So, @Barsoom, does this do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
$pattern = '/([a-zA-Z]+=\d+)/';
```